# Heteroscedasticity and bias shown in residual plots, lme

Tags: mixed-model, heteroscedasticity, bias, lme4-nlme, residuals

I have been fitting a linear mixed-effect model. The residual plots are not desirable. I have found many posts telling me the first is heteroscedastic, and the second is biased. But I can't find info telling me how should I refit the model to solve the problem. The codes are as shown below.

```
m1 = lme(life ~ 1 + Year, random = ~ 1 | Country, data = suit, method = "ML")
```

[image]

```
m7 = lme(life ~ 1 +hospitalden+radioden+DTP3,random = ~ 1 | Country, na.action=na.exclude,data = suit, method = "REML")
```

[image]

Comment: OK, we need more information about how you constructed these model but let's start with the obvious stuff: Can you understand why for example the second plot is problematic? It seems that you consistently under-estimate your fitted value when the true is low (~60) and over-estimate your fitted value when the true value is high (~75). Do you think there is some variable that you are missing and could mitigate this effect? Have you tried an AR(1) structure for your errors?

Comment: @usεr11852 Please see my another post: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/210084/hierarchical-linear-mixed-effects-model