# Hierarchical, Linear mixed-effects model

Tags: mixed-model, multilevel-analysis

The aim of my task is to ""investigate whether and how various factors affect the evolution of the life expectancy"". The data includes country, year (just a few and discontinuous like 1990 2007 2011, so in factor form. Or should I treat it as integers?), life expectancy and the factors of interest. One row of observation for each country-year combination. Part of the code that I have written:

```
m3 = lme(life ~ 1 + Year+GNI+cellular, random = ~ 1 |Country, na.action=na.exclude,data = suit, method = "REML")

m4 = lme(life ~ 1 + Year+GNI+cellular,random = ~ 1+Year|Country, na.action=na.exclude, data = suit, method = "REML")
```

I am not sure whether my code/model suits the aim of this task? The country is indicated as a group-level variable in the R output. Should the year be treated as group variable as well?

Besides, how should it be coded if the year is 'continuous' like 2011 2012 2013?